# show the inequality holds for the matrix relation

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

How do I choose examples where this inequality holds for the euclidean and infinite norm?
$$\frac{1}{||A^{-1}|| \; ||A||} \frac{||r||}{||b||} \le \frac{||e||}{||x||} \le ||A|| \; ||A^{-1}|| \frac{||r||}{||b||}$$

I just picked arbitrary $A$, $x$, and $e$ and then found $r$ and $b$ by the relation $Ax=b$ and $Ae=r$.  But I am thinking there might be a better way.  Any tips?

Comment: One of the simplest ways may be to pick any non-zero number $\lambda$, put $A=\lambda I$, and $r,b,x,e$ any vectors with norm $1$.